# More irrational than the Golden Ratio?

Tags: number-theory, golden-ratio

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sj8Sg8qnjOg), $\varphi$ is the most irrational number, due to its continued fraction form having $1$, the smallest natural number, in the denominators.

Is it not possible to construct a "more irrational" number by using $0$?

For example,

$\iota = 1 + \cfrac{1}{0 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{0 + \cfrac{1}{1+\cdots} } } }$

Based on the argument in the video, this would appear to be more irrational.

What am I missing?

Comment: This number is $1+1+1+1+...$ because the recipricals cancel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No because
$$\iota = 1 + \cfrac{1}{0 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{0 + \cfrac{1}{1+\cdots} } } }
= 1 + \cfrac{1}{ \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{ \cfrac{1}{1+\cdots} } } }$$\
$$=1 + 1+\cfrac{1} {\cfrac{1}{1+\cdots}}=1+1+1+\ldots $$

Comment: I don't understand how you go from form two to three, if anything, it looks like the $1/1$s would cancel, and it would be identical to the continued fraction form of $\varphi$ - which I guess also answers my question.

Comment: No, when two of the $1$’s cancel the rest is in the numerator, not the denominator